# Get int value out of pfquery to change settings objective-c

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Im trying to work with a script thats in objective c i want to make an int i can access throughout view did load to change settings or the viewcontroller but it doesn't work like swift and i get a null out of the pfquery so i tried to make an array and couldn't get anything out of the query with that as well

what is the best way to set up and int variable and set it in the pfquery then use if statements later on

here is some of my code

```
__block int setting = 0;

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"test"];
[query whereKey:@"testActive" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu scores.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
             setting = [[object objectForKey:@"testSetting"] intValue];
         // When checked in the loop i get all the right data   
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];

// When checked here i get settings = 0 when it should be 1
if (setting == 0) {
     self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

} else if (setting == 1) {
    self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
}

if (setting == 3) {
    [self.segmentedControl setEnabled:YES];
}else {
    [self.segmentedControl setEnabled:NO];
}
```

But when i check the setting int its always 0 but if i log in the loop is gives me the correct number

thanks for your help

Comment: How and where do you check `setting`?

Comment: I check it before the if statement with NSLog(@” print int %d”, setting); then check if (setting == 1) but the results are 0

Comment: But you said that it is not 0, if you log it. Please enter the checks in your code, so everyone can see it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help but i figured it out..

findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock was not completing before i did the if statements

so i moved the code into a new function which i ran when the PFQuery was completed giving me the correct int